# Pivot Table to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, pivot-table

I have this pivot table:

```
[in]:unit_d

[out]:
                         units
store_nbr   item_nbr    
   1            9        27396
                28        4893
                40        254
                47        2409
                51        925
                89        157
                93        1103
                99        492

    2           5         55104
                11        655
                44        117125
                85        106
                93        653
```

I want to have a dictionary with 'store_nbr' as the key and 'item_nbr' as the values.
So, `{'1': [9, 28, 40,...,99], '2': [5, 11 ,44, 85, 93], ...}`

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: How do I make a dictionary with 'store_nbr' as the key and 'item_nbr' as the values from the pivot table shown.

Comment: What did you pivot from? Would a `groupby` from there work? (is a dictionary to start with.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.0/groupby.html) here, after resetting the index to make it into columns:

```
>>> d = unit_d.reset_index()
>>> {k: v.tolist() for k, v in d.groupby("store_nbr")["item_nbr"]}
{1: [9, 28, 40, 47, 51, 89, 93, 99], 2: [5, 11, 44, 85, 93]}
```